# Scope a variable when assigning inside an if condition

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to scope a variable that is assigned within an if statement's condition?

The following will of course assign `el` to my element and will be globally scoped (as will `date`).

```
if (el = document.querySelector('.footer__year'), el) {
    var date = new Date();
    el.textContent = date.getFullYear();
}
```

But say I wrap that in an iife.

```
(function() {
    if (el = document.querySelector('.footer__year'), el) {
        var date = new Date();
        el.textContent = date.getFullYear();
    }
})();
```

`el` is still accessible via `window.el` but `date` is not.

Using `if (var el = document.querySelector('.footer__year'))` ends up with an unexpected token error.

Is there a way to scope this?

Also, I am aware that the following would fix my issue.

```
(function() {
    var el = document.querySelector('.footer__year');
    if (el) {
        var date = new Date();
        el.textContent = date.getFullYear();
    }
})();
```

But would like to know if this is even possible!

**UPDATE**

Overall variable scoping is not the problem here (the last example works just fine and `el` is not globally scoped), it is the ability to declare vs. assign a variable within the condition of an if statement.

Comment: `var el; if (el = .....`

Comment: The last one is the closest to what you want.  Even with ES6, `let` is not scoped to if statements in that way.

Comment: The core problem with then presented code is “var”/“let” are not expressions: fix this and then the underlying scoping rules can be discussed.

Comment: I disagree with the 'possible duplicate'. I was unclear on variable assignment vs. declaration within the condition of an `if` statement. Thanks @MarkMeyer for clarifying!

Comment: I agree @MJ12358, I don't think that question answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition inside of the `if` parenthesis needs to be an expression. `var`, `const` and `let` declarations are statements, which means you can't declare a variable with the `if` condition (even though you can *assign* a variable, because assignment is an expression).

You can take advantage of block scoping with `let` or `const` to avoid the IEFE:

```js
var el = 100 // outside
{ let el = 5
  if (el === 5) {
        console.log("inside:", el)
  }
}
console.log("outside:", el)  // still outside
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, **no**. There is no way you can prevent an assignment in an `if` statement from being hoisted globally.

A workaround for this (though a terrible one-off that still flashes the variable in the global scope) would be to simply use `delete window[var]` which will remove the variable from the `global` scope after use. It's not advisable and if you showed your boss they'd either insist you get more training or send you off to greener pastures, but the result is more or less similar.

```js
(function() {
    if (el = document.querySelector('.footer__year'), el) {
        var date = new Date();
        el.textContent = date.getFullYear();
        delete window["el"];
    }
})();
console.log(el);
```

```html
<div class="footer__year"></div>
```

There are a slew of problems with doing the above. At worst you'll be rewriting variables in Global Scope and then deleting them, causing the rest of your code not to function and throwing an error, at best you'll be performing more operations for no real reason, and making your code much less clear to others since there's effectively an invisible declaration. It's honestly just a mess that's best to, and easy to, avoid.

TLDR; **No.** Utilize proper declarative statements and the appropriate keywords and remain employed/happy.